# Read binary data from UDP to model

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

In my app I am receiving binary data through UDP, I wrote a binary reader that is going field by field and reading appropriate type and assigning it to model manually. Is there a way to define model in a way that will tell some kind of (de)serializer where to look for certain field instead of assigning everything?

Some fields may be arrays - their sizes are known and fixed, but model is unaware of this.

Example (current code):

```
byte Field1 = binaryReader.ReadByte();
sbyte Field2 = binaryReader.ReadSByte();
float[] Field3 = ...
//etc.
```

Desired code:

```
public class Model
{
   [BinaryPosition(1)]
   public byte Field1 { get; set;}
   [BinaryPosition(2)]
   public sbyte Field2 { get; set; }
   [BinaryPosition(3)]
   public float[] Field3 { get; set; }
}
//...
var model = BinaryDeserializer.Deserialize<Model>(byteBuffer);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of doing this, increasing in cost and complexity the more features you require.

Starting from the simplest, a POCO `struct` that works with, as POCO implies, plain C types (`byte`, `int`, basically `unmanaged` value types, no `string` or anything). In your example, that would be:

```
struct Model
{
    public byte Field1;
    public sbyte Field2;
}
```

There's many ways of converting your `byte[]` array to that structure, in order of efficiency (and version of .Net): `MemoryMarshal.Cast`, `fixed`+pointers and `Marshal.PtrToStructure`.

If you require more complex objects like strings, you need to use the `MarshalAs` attribute to declare how you want to pack the string, typically as a value array or less typically as a pointer, and then you need to use `Marshal.PtrToStructure` to have the marshaller silently handle all the extra copies for you. Obviously, much less efficient.

Comment: I don't have strings, but I do have arrays, I updated question as well

Comment: Arrays are fine as long as they're C-style arrays, ie with a constant size. You can use the `fixed` array keyword to have in-place value arrays.